# Доступ переменной в ООП JS

Tags: javascript

В открытом методе **init()**

```
this._todoContainer = document.querySelector(this._settings.todoContainer);
```

сюда я из настроек записываю название контейнера в документе.
 Значение есть всё как бы нормально.

Далее
я пользуюсь переменной в статическом методе

**this._todoContainer** // тоже делаю консоль лог и  тут пусто

```
this._todoContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template);
```

Так работает

```
document.querySelector('.dataTascksInfo').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template);
```

Почему не доступна переменная **this._todoContainer** в другие методы?

Comment: Как ты представляешь себе обращения к `this` в статическом методе? Что по-твоему является контекстным объектом таких методов?

Comment: @Alex .dataTascksInfo

Comment: @yar85 Я не знаю ответа на твой вопрос, можешь подсказать как вызывть  правильно эту переменну. В статическом методе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** В обычных методах, `this` указывает на *экземпляр* класса, а в статических - на *сам класс* (конструктор).

При обычном вызове, обращаться к свойствам экземпляра через `this`, можно только в нестатических методах.

---

### Детально:

Начнем с того, что классы в JS - это синтаксический "сахар" для описания объектных типов. И чтобы разобраться в ситуации, придется пробежаться по теории. Для этого, возьмем простой пример:

```js
class Box {
  constructor() { this.contents = []; }
  insert(something) { this.contents.push(something); }
  static isEmpty()  { return this.contents.length === 0; }
}

const box = new Box(); 
box.insert('cat'); 
console.log(Box.isEmpty());   // ошибка
```

**Как обрабатывается объявление "сахарного" класса:**

Интерпретатор создает функцию `Box()` - конструктор объектов типа `Box`.

Далее, этой функции добавляется свойство<sup>1</sup> `prototype` со значением в виде объекта, который будет наследоваться экземплярами. Прототип содержит методы "класса" - в данном случае, это только метод `insert()`<sup>2</sup>.

Статические методы становятся собственными методами функции-конструктора. В непосредственные свойства прототипа они не попадают.

**Как работают вызовы методов:**

Сначала выполняется поиск метода в объекте экземпляра, а затем в прототипах (по цепочке наследования "вверх", от ближайших предков к более дальним). Как только метод найден, поиск прекращается. Если не найден - выбрасывается исключение.

При вызове метода из прототипа, он временно "привязывается" к экземпляру, от имени которого вызван - и `this` внутри метода указывает на этот конкретный экземпляр<sup>3</sup>.

**Вызов статических методов** работает аналогично.
Но так как эти методы не в прототипе, и являются "собственностью" конструктора, вызываем мы от его имени - а значит, `this` внутри таких методов указывает на конструктор... у которого нет свойств экземпляров. Именно поэтому, в примере возникает ошибка при обращении из статического метода к свойству `contents`<sup>4</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Функции в JS являются объектами, и могут иметь свойства.

<sup>2</sup> Прототип также содержит свойство `constructor`, которое является ссылкой на саму функцию-конструктор (`Box.prototype.constructor === Box`).

<sup>3</sup> И не имеет значения, насколько "далеко" по цепочке наследования находится вызываемый метод. То есть, если бы мы в примере вызвали `box.hasOwnProperty(...)`, метод из более дальнего предка `Object` - он тоже выполнился бы так, будто является собственным методом `box`.

<sup>4</sup> Несмотря на то что это свойство создается конструктором - при использовании оператора `new`, `this` указывает на объект экземпляра еще до его возврата и присваивания переменнной `box`.

Comment: _такие методы находятся в прототипе конструктора класса_ - если бы они были в **прототипе** - их как раз можно было бы вызвать через имя экземпляра

Comment: @Grundy, Ок, а как следует понимать _« For each ClassElement m in order from methods { If IsStatic of m is false, then { Let status be the result of performing PropertyDefinitionEvaluation for m with arguments proto and false. } } »_ из спецификации ES6 (14.5.14)?

Comment: В чтении заклинаний из стандарта мне еще долго практиковаться... насколько понимаю сейчас, работает это следующим образом: из определения класса создается конструктор (функция), в прототип которого свойствами помещаются статические методы - таким образом, по цепочке наследования они (статик методы) доступны через имя класса, но не через имя экземпляров (т.к. прототип конструктора и прототип экземпляров это разные объекты). В чем именно тут ошибка?

Comment: Просто если эти методы на самом деле записываются в свойства функции-конструктора, а нее в ее прототип, то как же  тогда работает наследование сахарных классов, когда статик методы родителя доступны в потомках... через копирование что ли... ох сложнаааа

Comment: пункт 21: [Let status be the result of performing PropertyDefinitionEvaluation for m with arguments F and false.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation) - где `F` - это функция конструктор: `14. Let F be constructorInfo.[[Closure]].`

Comment: @Grundy, Точно ведь, вот я креведко. Спасибо!

Comment: У тебя, кстати, в твоей же цитате: _If IsStatic of m **is false**, then_

Comment: @Grundy, В том и дело)) проблема была в том что я коряво прочитал спецификацию, и этим сам себя запутал. Благодаря твоей подсказке, все вернулось на свои места - и для закрепления в памяти, накатал портянку текста в ответе.  :D